# Python Regex to find certain SQL statement from a SQL script (multiple SQL statements) and transform respecting the comments in input SQL

Tags: python, sql, regex

I'm trying to find certain type of SQL statements from a list of SQLs for examples CTAS and then do some tranformation.

Input :

```
       sqltexts = """
   --drop table  test_schema.test_table;

/*
create table table2 as select * from table3 ;
*/


create table table4 as (select * from table2);


create table table5 as select * from table 3 where id =1 -- and  date ='2013-01-01' ;

    """
```

Expected output:
Only 3rd and 4th statements have to be transformed as 1st and 2nd statement are commented and 4th statement should leave the comment section as it is

```
--drop table  test_schema.test_table;

/*
create table table2 as select * from table3 ;
*/


<transformed_sql> ;


<transformed_sql> where id =1 -- and  date ='2013-01-01' ;
```

However, I'm not able to respect the comments here. What I do is find the single line and multiline comments remove them from the input and then do the transformation. I would like to keep the comment as it is.

Output I get

```
<transformed_sql> ;

<transformed_sql> where id =1 ;
```

This removes all the comments from the input which I do not want even though output SQL serves the objective.

Python code I'm using:

```
sqlStatements = sqltexts.strip().split(';') # to split input SQL script into statements
rgx = re.compile(r"(create\s+(?:table|[\s\S]*\s+table)\s+[\w\d.]+\s+\bas\b\s+[\s\S]*)",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)  # to find if statement is CTAS
rgxcomment = re.compile(r"(--[^\r\n]*)",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)  # to ignore single line comment
rgxmulticomment =  re.compile(r"(\/\*[\w\W]*?(?=\*)\*\/)",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE) # to ignore multiline comment
for index,item in enumerate(sqlStatements):
    x = rgxcomment.findall(item) # Removing single line comments
    if len(x)>0:
            for i in x:
                index = item.find(i)
                item = item[:index] + '' + item[index+len(i):]
    y = rgxmulticomment.findall(item)   # Removing multiline comments
        if len(y)>0:
            for i in y:
                index = item.find(i)
                item = item[:index] + '' + item[index+len(i):]
    m = rgxddl.search(item)
    if m:
        <I do my transformation>
```

Comment: I think you'll have a hell of a time doing this with regex, and if any SQL statement ever looks different than what you expected it'll break. I'd try this by first parsing the SQL (using e.g. [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/), seems to support comments as well) to tease out which tokens need to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks Seb, will look into sqlparse library